# how add view to subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I try to show in one view other, but it doesn't work

***my views***

General

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate, DatePickerDelegate, AddScriptPopoverViewDelegate>
```

2nd

```
@interface MyViewController : BaseViewController<UniversalViewNavigationDelegate, StarsSizeViewDelegate, SelectPopoverViewDelegate, MyTableViewDelegate>
```

3rd

```
@interface MyViewNavigationController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, MyTableViewDelegate>
```

in need to show my third view in second, but when i try in second, in viewDidload

```
MyViewNavigationController *tableVC = [[MyViewNavigationController alloc] initWithTableSize:CGSizeMake(380, 600)];
tableVC.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableVC];
```

last row saing me:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'MyViewNavigationController *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIView *'
```

and crush

Help me please :)

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but if you are going to be showing views from other controllers as subviews, you really should be using child view controllers. Have a search for "Container View Controllers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
[self.view addSubview:tableVC];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:tableVC.view];
```

Comment: And what about keeping a strong reference to the view controller?  Surely that will have an impact on the lifetime of the view it contains?

Comment: Right. I would store the VC as property with strong or retain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can only add the layout of type UIView or layout inherited from UIView, so change the code as given below.

```
MyViewNavigationController *tableVC = [[MyViewNavigationController alloc] initWithTableSize:CGSizeMake(380, 600)];
tableVC.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableVC.view];
```

Comment: And what about keeping a strong reference to the view controller? Surely that will have an impact on the lifetime of the view it contains?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make property like this in **.h** file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)MyViewNavigationController *tableVC;
```

and then do it in **.m** file

```
tableVC = [[MyViewNavigationController alloc] initWithTableSize:CGSizeMake(380, 600)];
tableVC.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableVC.view];
```